# how to id in url using php rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

Hi friends am using id and post title in url using .htaccess.
Am getting output like example.com/videos/1/hello-how-are-you

How can I make it as example.com/how-are-you..

Here is my .htaccess code..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/([a-z\-A-Z]+)   post.php?p_id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: How can `post.php` be loaded without `id`?

Comment: @anubhava Its been loaded by id but I dont want to show id in url is there any way

Comment: only if you make the pretty urls unique

Comment: @anubhava is there any reference for this

Comment: @aelor how can I make then pretty urls unique

Comment: say you save a column in your table of videos 'pretty_url' and save a pretty url 'kittens-and-puppies' which is unique and then in the php you can write to retrieve the video based on the pretty url instead of requiring an id

Comment: @aelor thank you am trying it